# Tkinter assign a unique function for each object

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
class SubjectDashboard(object):

    def __init__(self, frame, name, linkFunction):
        self.name = name
        self.frame = frame
        subject_title = tk.Label(self.frame, text=self.name, fg=secondaryColour, bg=primaryColour, font=subjectTitleFont)
        subject_title.place(relwidth=1, relheight=.2)
        subject_title.bind("Button-1", linkFunction)
        subject_title.bind("<Enter>", hover)
        subject_title.bind("<Leave>", unhover)
```

I would like to have the linkFunction be a unique function for each object but this doesn't work. Is there a way that I can bind the button for each object to a separate function?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Note: I have very little clue with what I am doing, so this is what I have cobbled together and by no means do I think that it is accurate, efficient or correct.

Comment: Can you please specify what you mean by a unique function? Do you mean that it performs differently for each object?

Comment: I mean a separate function for each object - functions. Ideally as if it were an argument that could be assigned during the creation of each class.